# is it possible to get multiple results sorted by best match?

Tags: api, geocoding, mapquest

I need the mapquest geocoding API to return multiple results that best match an incomplete or incorrect address. Is that possible or the API can only return one single result that is correct or not?

Answer (score 2):

The MapQuest Geocode API returns results in the order of the most likely match determined by MapQuest.com usage. If an exact match is found, only one result is returned.